# In the Undercover heist, what's the best way to use the planks?

Tags: payday-the-heist

In this heist (shipped with the Wolfpack DLC), you can use planks to barricade the windows and the vents.

[image: Using planks in Undercover heist]

Since the cops (especially the snipers, pretty dangereous in this heist) can blow the barricades on windows in only a few shots, leaving you exposed, does anyone know if there's something useful to make of these planks?

Also, how long will the barricaded vents hold ?  Is it more interesting to condamn all the vents rather than the "key" windows (for instance, those in the server room, or the ones covering your way out on the roof, at the end of the heist) ?

Comment: There is plenty of cover on your way out, and you can fall back into the stairwell. I would suggest covering the windows in the server room. Unless you have a very good counter-sniper you will get absolutely wrecked by snipers without those windows boarded.

Comment: Okay but the point is that the snipers are blowing up the planks way too easily... So it doesn't really sound like a viable solution. Thanks for the contribution anyway !

Comment: Yeah I agree they can *feel* wasted, but you can collect a large number of them and even having a few moments without sniper fire hitting you is worth it. For reference watch Team Heist go at it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsO7vs3oezE&t=0m40s

Answer (score 1):

Many people believe that you should put the planks on the windows to block sniper fire, however this is very incorrect because then you can't kill the snipers. This tip is especially important on higher difficulties because you need to kill the snipers quickly before activating the final step of the hack, before running. You should also always make sure that you place planks on the roof, next to the power boxes. This is so you can quickly grab the power back when it goes down on the roof. Also put as many planks as you can near the escape, so the route will be easier. You will have to hope the shortcut is open.